# Transport Equation $u_t + bDu = -cu$ with initial condition $u=g$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Having trouble finishing. Given the PDE,

$$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} + b \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} = -cu$$

by method of characteristics we have that:

$$
\begin{matrix} \dfrac{dt}{ds} = 1 \iff t=s & \text{letting} \space\ t(0) = 0, & \text{we know} \space\ \space\ t=s. \\
& & \\
\dfrac{dx}{ds} = b \iff x = bs & \text{letting} \space\ x(0) = x_0, & \text{we know} \space\ \space\ x=bs+x_0 = bt + x_0. \\
& & \\
\dfrac{du}{ds} = -cu \iff u = e^{-cs} & \text{letting} \space\ u(0) = u_0, & \text{we know} \space\ \space\ u = u_0e^{-cs} = u_0e^{-ct}.
\end{matrix}
$$

Not really sure how to write down $u$ explicitly from this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close at the solution. All that is left is to invert $x_0$. You are given the initial condition $u=g$. By convention and considering you let $t(0)=0$, I believe this means $u(x,0)=g(x)$. This implies $u_0=g(x_0)$. From your equation for $x$, we know
$$x=bt+x_0\implies x_0=x-bt$$
Now plugging these into the equation you found for $u$ gives the result:
$$u=u_0e^{-ct}=g(x_0)e^{-ct}=g(x-bt)\,e^{-ct}$$
Plugging $u$ into your original PDE confirms the result.